# Umbraco in Linux Docker

Tags: linux, docker, umbraco

Is it possible to get an Umbraco CMS site working on a Linux server via Docker? I've found a few articles that suggest that you can get .NET running in Docker, but so far I can't get anything working.

Comment: I suggest you to add more info regarding the failed attemps and  mention error messages you get, so other members can help you.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a place to ask _programming related questions_.

Comment: Maybe you should try first and if you found problems, write a question with detailed error messages, but not this kind of questions.

Comment: To answer your question, no. You cannot yet run umbraco in docker on linux since it uses .net framework instead of .net core. You can however run Umbraco in docker on Windows server.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run Umbraco on any linux based server yet (Docker container or not) since it requires .NET Framework (and will not run on .NET Core) and both Umbraco and some of the dependencies required by Umbraco doesn't really work with Mono.

There's no official plans on when Umbraco will run fully on .NET Core. It will not be any time in the near future unfortunately. Current version 7 and the next version 8 will require .NET Framework.

As mentioned though - it is possible to run it in a Windows based Docker container.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the OP is asking whether Umbraco can be run in a Docker Container that's running on linux, not a container running Linux.  The Docker Container itself could be running Windows 2016 Server Core, and would happily host Umbraco I think?

Comment: Docker containers are not running a OS - it is not virtualization. The containers are "contained environments" running the application(s) with dependencies - on the underlying OS (which would be linux in this case). So no - you unfortunately cannot host Umbraco here since you cannot host a normal .NET framework 
application in a linux container unless using Mono (which doesn't work with Umbraco).

Comment: Oh and just to be clear :) - you cannot host a Windows container on a Linux host (officially that is - I think there might be some experimental feature toying with this option though).